# Redirecionar de domínio para sub-domínio com htacess

Tags: php, linux

Estou com problemas para migrar de um site x para outro y em um subdominio.

EX:

siteantigo.com

para

subdominio.sitenovo.com

Criei o htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdominio.sitenovo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

O problema que ele não redireciona certo.
Ele vai pra raiz sempre nunca indo para o link do antigo para o novo:

Ex:

siteantigo.com/categoria/link

para

subdominio.sitenovo.com

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso resolve:

```
Redirect 301 ^(www.)?siteantigo\.com\/(.*)$ http://subdominio.sitenovo.com/$1
```

Comment: Deu erro: Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.